# Conversion of an outlook datetime to date in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, type-conversion

Please see below code.

```
output_file = open('./outlook_farming_001.csv','wb')    
output_writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter = ",", encoding='latin2')
outlook = 
win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders['Inbox']
messages=inbox.items;    
output_writer.writerow(['Date','Sender','Sent To','Subject']);

for i,message in enumerate(messages):              # enumerated the items
    try:    
        date1 = message.LastModificationTime         
        subject = message.subject                   
        date = datetime.datetime.strftime(date1[:-3], '%Y-%m-%d 
           %H:%M:%S+%f');
        d = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
        print(d);  
    except Exception as e:
        ()
```

I am trying to print `d` in a sample `dd/mm/yyyy` format but not getting output. The normal format of `date1` fetched is `2018-06-08 17:05:49+00:00`

Answer (score 0):

if you want date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format change

```
d = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

to

```
d = date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

And just an FYI. You do not need the semi-colon `;` in python.

Comment: lol yeah semi-colon i have the habit of putting, because mostly i work with java and pl/sql